# Why Spring doesn't see @Configuration when it loads a bean from applicationContext.xml?

Tags: spring, configuration, spring-java-config

I have the following applicationContext.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

    <bean class="com.app.config.AppConfig"></bean>      
</beans>
```

And the following config class:

```
package com.app.config;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.app")
public class AppConfig {
    // actual beans definition
    @Bean
    ...

    @Bean
    ...

    @Bean
    ...
}
```

But if I run the app then Spring will not load the AppConfig cause I get  `NullPointerExceptions` on `@Autowired` dependencies. So it is like Spring doesn't load the JavaConfig `@Bean` definitions inside the AppConfig class but treats the class as a simple `@Component` and not a `@Configuration` component which can in turn contain bean definitions.

Everything works only when I add the `<context:component-scan>` definition inside the applicationContext.xml instead of the `@ComponentScan` annotation inside AppConfig, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

    <bean class="com.app.config.AppConfig"></bean>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.app" />
</beans>
```

And AppConfig becomes simply:

```
package com.app.config;

@Configuration // no more @ComponentScan (it's inside applicationContext.xml)
public class AppConfig {
    // actual beans definition
    @Bean
    ...

    @Bean
    ...

    @Bean
    ...
}
```

Now, why does Spring doesn't see the @Configuration annotation when it loads the `AppConfig` bean from `applicationContext.xml` if `applicationContext.xml` doesn't have `<context:component-scan>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are missing annotation-config in your xml. Include the below in your appcontext.xml. This is required to process your annotation. Thanks.

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

Comment: Thanks, it was the missing thing!